# How do make a copy of a javascript object which only retains data, but not functions?

Tags: javascript

I am preparing big objects and so I have also added some functions to maintain them. I need to send this object across to serve incoming queries. I don't see any benefit in sending the functions too. I just want to send the data only. How do I strip an object of its functions, to make it leaner while sending.

EDIT : confirming using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse works

```
l={}
Object {}
l.zz=19
19
l.f = function(){ console.log(this.zz) }
function (){ console.log(this.zz) }
l
Object {zz: 19, f: function}
JSON.stringify(l)
"{"zz":19}"
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(l))
Object {zz: 19}
```

Comment: simply `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`

Answer (score 3):

Just take JSON.stringify() to make a string and parse it.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you use `JSON.stringify` to make the object into a JSON string. It will put all public fields(assigned by `this`) that are not functions but values into the JSON string.

By then taking the output of `JSON.stringify` and putting it into `JSON.parse` you get a clean object without functions but purely values.

Basically what you only need to do is:

```
var clean = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectvariable));
```

Here is some example code splitting everything out step by step :-)
Hit F12 to see the output in console.

```js
/** Sample object with functions and values **/
function ObjectHolder() {
  this.x = "hello";
  this.y = "world";
  this.z = "universe";
  this.which = false;
  }
/** Make a string defined by boolean **/
ObjectHolder.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.x + " " +(this.which? this.y:this.z);
}
/** Sample object with functions and values **/
ObjectHolder.prototype.switchIt = function() {
  this.which = !this.which;
  }
/** instantiate object **/
var takeit = new ObjectHolder();
/** Show current output, to see if it works **/
console.log(takeit.toString());
/** Test inversion **/
takeit.switchIt();
/** output should be changed **/
console.log(takeit.toString());

/** Take the object and make it a string **/
var str = JSON.stringify(takeit);
/** Take the JSON string and turn it into an object **/
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
/** Show the differences between the values **/
console.log("ObjectHolder(var takeit) object with functions",takeit);
console.log("JSON string",str);
console.log("functionless object",obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a string and parse it:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))
```

Answer (score 1):

This function would perform a *deep* copy of data properties letting functions out:

```
function deepCopyObject(src)
{
    var tgt=[]
    for (var x in src)
    {
        var p=src[x]
        if (!(p instanceof Function))
        {
            if (p instanceof Object)
            {
                tgt[x]=copyObject(p)
            }
            else
            {
                tgt[x]=p
            }
        }
    }
    return tgt
}
```

To use it, just execute:

```
var myCopy=deepCopyObject(mySrc)
```

Comment: I actually need to do this cleaning a lot. Do you think this will work faster than JSON stringify + parse?

Comment: My thinking is I just need to do a shallow copy. 
  tgt[x]=copyObject(p) would become  tgt[x]=p

Comment: That is correct. For a shallow copy, you can avoid the recursive call.

Comment: I presume that it will be faster than serialize + parse, because it saves the creation of the serialized JSON string object, and it also saves the time of parsing.